# sync call in tableau javascript

Tags: javascript, tableau-api

I am trying to do sync call using tableau.

```js
var checkLen = $s_filter_i.length;
for (i = 0; i < checkLen; i++) {
    var filterValfscr = $s_filter_i[i].VALUE;
    Send_Tablo(filterValfscr);
}
```

When call this function `Send_Tablo(filterValfscr)` it runs the below code.

But the problem is before I get response form `getSummaryDataAsync()` it comes out of the function recalls `Send_Tablo(filterValfscr)` again I get the latest request data instead of first data request.

```js
function Send_Tablo() {
    var filter_indx = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('filter_indx'));
    var arry = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < filter_indx.s_filter_i.length; i++) {
        Attr_lab_name = filter_indx.s_filter_i[i].ATTRIBUTELABEL;
        arry.push(filter_indx.s_filter_i[i].VALUE);  
    }

    currentViz.getWorkbook().changeParameterValueAsync('Attribute_Label', filterValfscr, Attr_lab_name, arry);
    alert(filterValfscr);
    var fScr_data;
    sheet = currentViz.getWorkbook().getActiveSheet();
    sheet.getSummaryDataAsync(options).then(function (t) {
        data = t.getData();
        console.log("Data", data);
        frscr_demo();
    });

    function frscr_demo() {
        //var fScr_data;
        currentViz.getWorkbook().getActiveSheet().applyFilterAsync(Attr_lab_name, arry, tableau.FilterUpdateType.REPLACE);
        sheet = currentViz.getWorkbook().getActiveSheet();
        sheet.getSummaryDataAsync(options).then(function (t) {
            fScr_data = t.getData();
            console.log("FSCR", fScr_data);
            var aa = $(fScr_data).length;
        });
    }
}
```

What I am try to achieve is `Send_Tablo()` should run all the Async function first before running the second iteration of `Send_Tablo()` from the for loop.

Do let me known what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: From the name you can see it's `Async` so it won't happen instantly.

Comment: @ZohirSalakCeNa yeah i understood. Is there way in tableau to make it sync way or using promise can i achieve it?